# How do I reduce disk pressure on my kubernetes worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, system-monitoring

I have a self managed kubernetes cluster running on EC2s.
The disk pressure on few of the nodes is high.

I checked which directories are utilizing the most disk space

```
1.6G    ./snap
2.2G    ./usr
6.5G    ./run
16G     ./var
```

Digging in further

Its the kubelet and containerd directories that are utilizing max storage

```
root@worker3:/var/lib# du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h | tail -3
5.8G    ./kubelet
8.9G    ./containerd
16G     .
```

Inside these folders
kubelet

```
root@worker3:/var/lib/kubelet# du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h | tail -2
2.9G    ./pods
5.8G    .
```

Containerd

```
2.3G    ./io.containerd.content.v1.content
6.7G    ./io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs
```

```
root@worker3:/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots# ls
1     1210  1221  1252  1260  1439  1453  1461  1622  1631  1639  1649  1661  1669  1680  1710  1720  1728  1736  1744  1752  1760  1768  21  31  43   512  52   586  643  651  974  996
1000  1211  1222  1253  1261  1440  1454  15    1623  1632  1640  1650  1662  1670  1681  1712  1721  1729  1737  1745  1753  1761  1769  22  32  45   513  54   588  644  652  975  997
1001  1212  1223  1254  1262  1441  1455  1582  1624  1633  1641  1651  1663  1671  1686  1713  1722  1730  1738  1746  1754  1762  1770  23  35  46   514  55   589  645  653  986  998
1002  1213  1224  1255  1263  1442  1456  1584  1625  1634  1642  1653  1664  1673  1687  1715  1723  1731  1739  1747  1755  1763  1771  24  36  47   515  56   590  646  654  987
1197  1216  1225  1256  13    1443  1457  1585  1626  1635  1643  1654  1665  1674  17    1716  1724  1732  1740  1748  1756  1764  1772  25  37  48   516  569  592  647  655  988
1198  1217  1226  1257  14    1450  1458  1586  1627  1636  1644  1657  1666  1675  1707  1717  1725  1733  1741  1749  1757  1765  1775  26  39  50   517  583  593  648  656  991
1206  1219  1227  1258  1437  1451  1459  1587  1628  1637  1645  1658  1667  1676  1708  1718  1726  1734  1742  1750  1758  1766  18    29  40  51   518  584  594  649  7    992
1208  1220  1251  1259  1438  1452  1460  16    1630  1638  1646  1660  1668  1679  1709  1719  1727  1735  1743  1751  1759  1767  19    30  42  511  519  585  6    650  973  994
```

How do I know which files can be deleted without affecting any of the running pods or applications?